# Database for Basketball teams/games/scores per season. Table structure

Tags: python, mysql, sql, relational-database

I am creating a database for a Basketball Season.  At this point, I am keeping it simple, and storing tables:

-**League** id[PK], name->(NBA, NCAAM, etc)

-**Year** id[PK], league_id[FK], year->(2012-2013, 2011-2012, etc)

-**Team** id[PK], league_id[FK], name->(Bulls, Lakers, Etc)

-**Game** id[PK], home_team[FK], away_team[FK]

-**Score** id[PK], game_id[FK], home_score, away_score

My question is about table structure.  I am somewhat new to sql, but I want to be able to make calcuations based on database info.  For example:

Team A on the road, playing team B, where team A's road score avg is x and team B's home score average is y... and so on

Anything you see that screams DONT DO IT THAT WAY?  Just wanted you guys to take a quick look.

Eventually would like to develop a cross sport DB similar to this:

http://www.bc.edu/content/dam/files/schools/cas_sites/cs/local/bach/2008/08LawrenceChang.pdf

But want to start here to get a base scraping algorithm, and some basic stats to start out.  Let me know whatcha think.  Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 2):

At first glance I would put the scores in the game table and add a game date field.  I would rename the year table as season, and include start and stop dates.  Also consider adding a season id to the game table.

Comment: Ya you're totally right.  Game can just have home_team, home_score, etc.  Also will put 2 date fields in the Season table, for beginning and end of season, will certainly help distinguish the end of a season in 2013 and the beginning of the next in 2013!  Saweeeet!

Answer (score 0):

The Year and Score tables both seem unnecessary to me. They can easily be added onto the Game table (including both a date and a season field for the Year).

Also I don't see why you need to generate the auto-increment primary key on the League table. The League name by itself would work perfectly fine, or better yet get rid of the League table altogether and just use [ENUM](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/enum.html) on the league field in the Team table.